# How to create a nested custom page in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, inherited-resources

I need to create a nested custom page inside a resource.

The route should be like this:
`/admin/quizzes/:id/my_custom_page`

The problem is that we can't use `belongs_to` in `ActiveAdmin::Page`.

I could create the route manually of course, but would be great if the AA could handle this for us.

The documentation says nothing and the code is not so simple. :(

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `member_action`:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Quiz do

  member_action :my_custom_page, method: :get do
  end

end
```

And this will generate a route at `/admin/quizzes/:id/my_custom_page`

[Reference](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html)

Comment: So obsviously... :P   But do you know how to attach a `Page` instance to this `member_action`? Thanks!

Comment: This action will render the view under the path `app/views/admin/quizzes/my_custom_page.html.erb`

Comment: Yep! But could we have a `Page` instance instead? Thus we could take benefit of AA's dsl.

Comment: `member_action` does exactly what `Page` does, but related to a model. That is what you need, don't?

Comment: There are [some features](http://activeadmin.info/docs/10-custom-pages.html#available_features) that couldn't be used when working with .erb (unless you include some modules).